# using LIKE on another column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

In the table `tags` I have the field `id`. In the table `tastings` I have a field `tags` which is a list of id numbers separated by commas, for example `2,4,5`. The database is MySQL.

Now I am trying to count how many times each tag is used in total. But I am stuck with the LIKE part. I have tried the following, all giving a syntax error:

```
SELECT tags.id, tag, FROM tags, tastings WHERE tags LIKE tags.id + '%'

SELECT tags.id, tag, FROM tags, tastings WHERE tags LIKE tags.id & '%'

SELECT tags.id, tag, FROM tags, tastings WHERE tags LIKE CONCAT(tags.id, '%')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which DBMS?  It might matter.

Comment: Did you try this ? SELECT tags.id, tag, FROM tags, tastings WHERE tags LIKE '%' + tags.id + '%'

Comment: I use MySQL. And yes I have tried those.

Comment: SQL concatenation operator is `||`.

Comment: If I try the || I get weird results, it seems to be not the same as using CONCAT()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I helps if you post the error, but you have an extra comma after the select list. Also, you might need to qualify `tags`, since it is both a table and a column.

Try this:

```
SELECT tags.id, tag
FROM tags, tastings
WHERE tastings.tags LIKE CONCAT('%', tags.id, '%')
```

or better, use the new join syntax:

```
SELECT tags.id, tag
FROM tags
JOIN tastings on tastings.tags LIKE CONCAT('%', tags.id, '%')
```

Note the sandwiching of tag.id in `%` so you find the id anywhere in it.

Warning: This join will hit id `4` when tags are `13,14,15` (there's a `4` in `14`), so unless your ids are all less than 10, you'll need to rethink your join criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified your DBMS so I'm taking a guess at what is supported.

How about

```
SELECT tags.id, tastings.tag
FROM tags 
    INNER JOIN tastings  
        ON tastings.tags like '%' + tags.id + '%'
```

This should work (again, depending on your DBMS) but you should really normalize your data, this type of thing really isn't going to scale/perform well.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query.

```
select t.id , count(t.id) from tag t , tastings tas where tas.tags like '%' ||t.id||'%'
group by t.id;
```